# Receive Grafana resolved alert when restarted pod succeeds

Tags: kubernetes, prometheus, grafana, alert

I want to get a Grafana alert whenever a `Pod` (scheduled by `CronJob` and related `Job`) restarts (red) and an additional resolution alert (green) when it succeeds.

The restart alert rule is:

```
increase(kube_pod_container_status_restarts_total{namespace=\"mynamespace\"}[30m])
```